# The Navigation Architecture Component animation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I've been following the sample from [NavigationBasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample)

but used newest library for navigation:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05"
```

and androidx library:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
```

and add to bundle.gradle

```
androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
}
```

all works except animation. It is bug maybe or ?

this is my nav_graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/categoryFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
        android:name="com.sample.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="Categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_itemsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/itemsFragment"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/itemsFragment"
        android:name="com.sample.ItemsFragment"
        android:label="Items"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_items" >

        <argument android:name="cat_id" android:defaultValue="-1" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

and my navhost fragment:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_host"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>
```

Comment: where did you test it, what device? are you sure that animation enabled on device in settings?

Comment: yes, i am sure... i tried to build their sample, and its work..but my sample don't work..

Comment: add your code pls

Answer (score 8):

I think you use this code:

```
findNavController(it, R.id. fragment_nav_host).navigate(R.id. itemsFragment)
```

If this is true, then it is wrong. You must use the action you wrote with your animation.

Correct will be:

```
findNavController(it,R.id.fragment_nav_host).navigate(R.id.action_categoryFragment_to_itemsFragment)
```

Comment: Animations are applied to action. So navigating using action is must to let the animation work
^ this is the correct answer

Comment: @DavidRefaeli im rly happy :3